# Fancybox - open a gallery manually by element name rather than href

Tags: jquery

I have the manual gallery link working as per fancyBox demo, which opens the hrefs specified in the js. Only I'd like to find a way of opening the other images on the page instead - so I guess by targeting an element (li, img, or even a class?) rather than href. Is this possible?

Can't find any documentation on specifically this! Thanks in advance...

http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/4098/

```js
$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
  $.fancybox.open([
    {
     type: 'image',
      href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
      title : '1st title'
    }, {
     type: 'image',
      href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
      title : '2nd title'
    }, {
     type: 'image',
      href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg'
    }
  ], {
    helpers : {
      thumbs : {
        width: 75,
        height: 50
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add an id to an image and then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fancybox($('#img1')).trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: @user2188661 see my answer

Comment: I don't think this does anything? Could you perhaps try on the jsfiddle in my original post and you'll see what I mean? Thanks!  http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/4098/

Comment: @user2188661 See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j_mmontero/STgGM/4100/

Comment: Ah I see! What I'm after is actually to try and enter a lightbox gallery of the images to  be able to go left, right, close etc. So I tried adding `$.fancybox($('img')).trigger('click');` using 'img' instead of ID. This works, only it makes my images disappear after you've scrolled through them! 

Seems like I'm missing some small detail in this syntax - see what happens when you scroll through all 4 images (after clicking 'open gallery') and keep going. They disappear off the page! http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/4102/

Comment: It's actually easier to see it on this one http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/4104/ You can see each image disappear as you click through left or right! By the time you are the end, there are no images remaining!